# Using pyenv to switch between two system versions of Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x

Is it possible to have [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) switch between two system versions of Python? I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, and it comes shipped with both `python2` (v2.7.6) and `python3` (v3.4.0) commands. (And the command `python` links to `python2`).

After installing `pyenv`, and typing `pyenv versions` it shows only one entry with `* system`, which is apparently the `python2` version..

Do I need to install Python3 with pyenv, in order for it to be able to switch between Python2 and Python3? (I hope it is not necessary since I already have it installed)

Note: I know that I could just type `python3 prog.py` to run Python3, or I could insert an `alias python=python3` in my `~/.bashrc` but this is not what I am looking for. I am more interested to have programs with the `#! /usr/bin/env python` shebang to run with the Python3 interpreter..

Comment: I suspect you can do this in Ubuntu with `update-alternatives`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin just for this case: [pyenv-register](https://github.com/doloopwhile/pyenv-register).